# Minimizing geodesic between all of its points in complete non-compact manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I am working on a problem from Do-Carmo Riemannian Geometry book, I have been working on it all day, I would appreciate any advice or suggestion, the problem says:

Let p be a point in a complete, non-compact riemannian manifold M. Prove there is a geodesic $ \gamma : [0 , \infty] \to M $ with initial value $\ \gamma (0) = p$, having the property that $ \gamma$ is a minimal geodesic between  $\gamma(0)$ and $\gamma(s)$ for any $ s \in [0, \infty ]$ .

My ideas:
If there did not exist that  geodesic, that would mean that for every $v \in TpM$ with  $|v|=1$ I would have an correspondence : v  $\to$ max{t} such that the geodesic $exp_p(tv)$ minimizes the distance. If that  transformation is continuous, It would reach it maximum and being $exp_p$ suprayective (Hopf-Rinow theorem) I could conclude that M is compact, Contradiction!  But of course i can not see why that transformation would be continuous.

Another idea would be that at points where the geodesic don't minimize distance, For the Hopf-Rinow theorem, there would be another geodesic which would minimize,  therefore that point is a critical point of $dexp_p$ and i get a Jacobi field. But I don't know what else i can do working on this idea.

Comment: Find a sequence $x_n$ s.t. $d(x,x_n)\rightarrow \infty$ and and find a convergent subsequence of minimizing geodesic segments $[xx_n]$

Comment: I can find a secuence $x_n$ such that $d(p,x_n) \to \infty$ because of non.compactnes, using that sequence How can i be sure that there exists a converget subsequence of geodesic segments ?

Comment: Each $x_n$ determine direction in $T_pM$ so that use a compactness of unit sphere in $T_pM$

Comment: Ohh.. I see taking their projections to the sphere right?